# Detox - The request was denied by service delegate (PBProcessManager) for reason: Security

Tags: ios, xcode, security, react-native, detox

Trying to upgrade from Detox 7.3.4 to 8.1.1

It appears to be loading from an apple tv instead of the phone I provide even when providing `--configuration`

package.json:

```
  "detox": {
    "configurations": {
      "ios.sim.debug": {
        "binaryPath": "member/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app",
        "build": "xcodebuild -workspace member/ios/MyApp.xcworkspace -scheme MyApp -configuration Debug  -sdk iphonesimulator -derivedDataPath member/ios/build",
        "type": "ios.simulator",
        "name": "iPhone 8"
      }
    }
  },
```

> etai$ `npm run detox`
>
> app@0.0.1 detox /Users/etai/Code/data/mobile
>   NODE_PATH=. detox test -- --artifacts-location='e2e/screenshots' --record-logs all
>
> node_modules/.bin/mocha e2e --opts e2e/mocha.opts --configuration ios.sim.debug      --grep :android: --invert  --record-logs all   --artifacts-location "e2e/screenshots/ios.sim.debug.2018-07-30 12-55-09Z"
>
> detox INFO:  [DetoxServer.js] server listening on localhost:49455...
>
> detox ERROR: [exec.js/EXEC_FAIL, #6] "/usr/bin/xcrun simctl io 368E25FE-3641-48F6-A47C-EA403E68EB85 screenshot "/dev/null"" failed with code = 2, stdout and stderr:
>
> detox ERROR: [exec.js/EXEC_FAIL, #6]
>
> detox ERROR: [exec.js/EXEC_FAIL, #6] An error was encountered processing the command (domain=SimulatorKit.SimDisplayScreenshotWriter.ScreenshotError, code=2):
>
> Error creating the image
>
> detox ERROR: [exec.js/EXEC_FAIL, #10] "/bin/cat /dev/null
>
> /Users/etai/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/368E25FE-3641-48F6-A47C-EA403E68EB85/data/tmp/detox.last_launch_app_log.out 2>/Users/etai/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/368E25FE-3641-48F6-A47C-EA403E68EB85/data/tmp/detox.last_launch_app_log.err && SIMCTL_CHILD_DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES="/Users/etai/Library/Detox/ios/d01d632fc9620831ab762e463575a0528084a3af/Detox.framework/Detox" /usr/bin/xcrun simctl launch --stdout=/tmp/detox.last_launch_app_log.out --stderr=/tmp/detox.last_launch_app_log.err 368E25FE-3641-48F6-A47C-EA403E68EB85 com.myapp.MyAppDebug --args -detoxServer ws://localhost:49455 -detoxSessionId 7a268b8c-8ece-f34d-a5d3-13ed361a4b57" failed with code = 1, stdout and stderr:
>
> detox ERROR: [exec.js/EXEC_FAIL, #10] com.myapp.MyAppDebug: -1
>
> detox ERROR: [exec.js/EXEC_FAIL, #10] An error was encountered processing the command (domain=FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain, code=1):
>   The request to open "com.myapp.MyAppDebug" failed.
>   The request was denied by service delegate (PBProcessManager) for reason: Security ("PBD] Denying open-application request for reason: Security (App 'com.myapp.MyAppDebug' looks unsafe for use on the internet; ").
>   Underlying error (domain=FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain, code=3):
>       The operation couldn’t be completed. [PBD] Denying open-application request for reason: Security (App 'com.myapp.MyAppDebug' looks unsafe for use on the internet; )
>       [PBD] Denying open-application request for reason: Security (App 'com.myapp.MyAppDebug' looks unsafe for use on the internet; )

1. Things I have tried:

   - Restarting my computer (v10.13.6) / xcode (v9.4.1) / etc.
   - Using different signing certificates
   - Using different simulators
   - `--configuration` flag

Full log with `--loglevel trace`

```
detox INFO:  [DetoxServer.js] server listening on localhost:49586...
detox DEBUG: [AsyncWebSocket.js/WEBSOCKET_OPEN] opened web socket to: ws://localhost:49586
detox TRACE: [AsyncWebSocket.js/WEBSOCKET_SEND] {"type":"login","params":{"sessionId":"67bd086e-af49-fd61-1de8-242636d659fe","role":"tester"},"messageId":0}
detox DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/LOGIN] role=tester, sessionId=67bd086e-af49-fd61-1de8-242636d659fe
detox DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/LOGIN_SUCCESS] role=tester, sessionId=67bd086e-af49-fd61-1de8-242636d659fe
detox TRACE: [AsyncWebSocket.js/WEBSOCKET_MESSAGE] {"type":"loginSuccess","params":{"sessionId":"67bd086e-af49-fd61-1de8-242636d659fe","role":"tester"},"messageId":0}

detox DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #0] /usr/bin/xcrun simctl list -j
detox TRACE: [exec.js/EXEC_SUCCESS, #0] {
  "devicetypes" : [...,
  {
    "state" : "Shutdown",
    "availability" : "(available)",
    "name" : "iPhone 8",
    "udid" : "87D92BC6-686E-4EB3-9F09-E8865A0BE0ED"
  }, ...],
  "runtimes" : [...,     {
  "buildversion" : "15F79",
  "availability" : "(available)",
  "name" : "iOS 11.4",
  "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-11-4",
  "version" : "11.4"
}, ...],
detox DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #1] applesimutils --list --byType "iPhone 8" --byOS "11.4"
detox DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_TRY, #1] Searching for device matching iPhone 8...
detox TRACE: [exec.js/EXEC_SUCCESS, #1] [...]
    detox TRACE: [exec.js/EXEC_SUCCESS, #2] Unknown command line option --byId, try --help!

detox DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #3] xcodebuild -version
detox TRACE: [exec.js/EXEC_SUCCESS, #3] Xcode 9.4.1
Build version 9F2000

detox DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #4] /usr/bin/xcrun simctl boot 368E25FE-3641-48F6-A47C-EA403E68EB85
detox DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_TRY, #4] Booting device 368E25FE-3641-48F6-A47C-EA403E68EB85
detox TRACE: [exec.js/EXEC_SUCCESS, #4] 
detox DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #5] /usr/bin/xcrun simctl bootstatus 368E25FE-3641-48F6-A47C-EA403E68EB85
detox TRACE: [exec.js/EXEC_SUCCESS, #5] Monitoring boot status for Apple TV (368E25FE-3641-48F6-A47C-EA403E68EB85).
[2018-07-30 13:14:38 +0000] Status=3, isTerminal=YES, Elapsed=00:02.
    Data Migration Failed


detox DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #6] /usr/bin/xcrun simctl io 368E25FE-3641-48F6-A47C-EA403E68EB85 screenshot "/dev/null"
detox ERROR: [exec.js/EXEC_FAIL, #6] "/usr/bin/xcrun simctl io 368E25FE-3641-48F6-A47C-EA403E68EB85 screenshot "/dev/null"" failed with code = 2, stdout and stderr:

detox ERROR: [exec.js/EXEC_FAIL, #6] 
detox ERROR: [exec.js/EXEC_FAIL, #6] An error was encountered processing the command (domain=SimulatorKit.SimDisplayScreenshotWriter.ScreenshotError, code=2):
Error creating the image

detox DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #7] /usr/bin/xcrun simctl uninstall 368E25FE-3641-48F6-A47C-EA403E68EB85 com.myapp.MyAppDebug
detox DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_TRY, #7] Uninstalling com.myapp.MyAppDebug...
detox TRACE: [exec.js/EXEC_SUCCESS, #7] 
detox DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_SUCCESS, #7] com.myapp.MyAppDebug uninstalled
detox DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #8] /usr/bin/xcrun simctl install 368E25FE-3641-48F6-A47C-EA403E68EB85 "/Users/etai/Code/data/mobile/member/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ApparMember.app"
detox DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_TRY, #8] Installing /Users/etai/Code/data/mobile/member/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ApparMember.app...
detox TRACE: [exec.js/EXEC_SUCCESS, #8] 
detox DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_SUCCESS, #8] /Users/etai/Code/data/mobile/member/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ApparMember.app installed
detox DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #9] /usr/bin/xcrun simctl terminate 368E25FE-3641-48F6-A47C-EA403E68EB85 com.myapp.MyAppDebug
detox DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_TRY, #9] Terminating com.myapp.MyAppDebug...
detox TRACE: [exec.js/EXEC_SUCCESS, #9] 
detox DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_SUCCESS, #9] com.myapp.MyAppDebug terminated
detox TRACE: [ArtifactsManager.js/LIFECYCLE] onBeforeLaunchApp { deviceId: '368E25FE-3641-48F6-A47C-EA403E68EB85',
  bundleId: 'com.myapp.MyAppDebug' }
detox DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_CMD, #10] /bin/cat /dev/null >/Users/etai/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/368E25FE-3641-48F6-A47C-EA403E68EB85/data/tmp/detox.last_launch_app_log.out 2>/Users/etai/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/368E25FE-3641-48F6-A47C-EA403E68EB85/data/tmp/detox.last_launch_app_log.err && SIMCTL_CHILD_DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES="/Users/etai/Library/Detox/ios/d01d632fc9620831ab762e463575a0528084a3af/Detox.framework/Detox" /usr/bin/xcrun simctl launch --stdout=/tmp/detox.last_launch_app_log.out --stderr=/tmp/detox.last_launch_app_log.err 368E25FE-3641-48F6-A47C-EA403E68EB85 com.myapp.MyAppDebug --args -detoxServer ws://localhost:49586 -detoxSessionId 67bd086e-af49-fd61-1de8-242636d659fe
detox DEBUG: [exec.js/EXEC_TRY, #10] Launching com.myapp.MyAppDebug...
detox ERROR: [exec.js/EXEC_FAIL, #10] "/bin/cat /dev/null >/Users/etai/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/368E25FE-3641-48F6-A47C-EA403E68EB85/data/tmp/detox.last_launch_app_log.out 2>/Users/etai/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/368E25FE-3641-48F6-A47C-EA403E68EB85/data/tmp/detox.last_launch_app_log.err && SIMCTL_CHILD_DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES="/Users/etai/Library/Detox/ios/d01d632fc9620831ab762e463575a0528084a3af/Detox.framework/Detox" /usr/bin/xcrun simctl launch --stdout=/tmp/detox.last_launch_app_log.out --stderr=/tmp/detox.last_launch_app_log.err 368E25FE-3641-48F6-A47C-EA403E68EB85 com.myapp.MyAppDebug --args -detoxServer ws://localhost:49586 -detoxSessionId 67bd086e-af49-fd61-1de8-242636d659fe" failed with code = 1, stdout and stderr:

detox ERROR: [exec.js/EXEC_FAIL, #10] com.myapp.MyAppDebug: -1

detox ERROR: [exec.js/EXEC_FAIL, #10] An error was encountered processing the command (domain=FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain, code=1):
The request to open "com.myapp.MyAppDebug" failed.
The request was denied by service delegate (PBProcessManager) for reason: Security ("PBD] Denying open-application request for reason: Security (App 'com.myapp.MyAppDebug' looks unsafe for use on the internet; <PBApplicationInfo: 0x7fc86e00b1b0; com.myapp.MyAppDebug (App-Debug); sdk: 11.4>").
Underlying error (domain=FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain, code=3):
    The operation couldn’t be completed. [PBD] Denying open-application request for reason: Security (App 'com.myapp.MyAppDebug' looks unsafe for use on the internet; <PBApplicationInfo: 0x7fc86e00b1b0; com.myapp.MyAppDebug (App-Debug); sdk: 11.4>)
    [PBD] Denying open-application request for reason: Security (App 'com.myapp.MyAppDebug' looks unsafe for use on the internet; <PBApplicationInfo: 0x7fc86e00b1b0; com.myapp.MyAppDebug (App-Debug); sdk: 11.4>)

detox TRACE: [ArtifactsManager.js/LIFECYCLE] onAfterAll
detox DEBUG: [DetoxServer.js/DISCONNECT] role=tester, sessionId=67bd086e-af49-fd61-1de8-242636d659fe
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears related to https://github.com/wix/detox/issues/853#issuecomment-407375505.

Where in 7.3.3 the name field corresponded to the AppleSimUtils --byName flag, it now only corresponds to the nested deviceType.name field, which is really a deviceType, not a name.

Comment: This is an issue and will be fixed soon.

Comment: Great! As a quick hack in the meantime I temporarily disabled all other device simulators.